# GCP / Firebase Functions: "Some functions failed to load"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm getting errors for the Firebase functions.

First I deploy the function from Firebase cli it's deploying successfully but when I open the Firebase functions I'm getting the below error
[image]

Even When opening the google cloud firebase functions there it's saying to me that the Firebase function failed to deploy.

> **What a controversial it is, firebase cli is saying success but Cloud is saying failed to deploy**

Here's the google cloud screenshot:
[image]

Could anyone please share why it's like that,

**Note**:

- Also update the permission under the IAM of google cloud but in vain.
- when open the google cloud it's there(the code I pushed) but on redeploying it again failed to deploy

Answer (score 0):

> i functions: updating **Node.js 10** function scheduledFunction(us-central1)...

Finally sorted the issue, just need to upgrade the nodejs version from 10 to the latest, currently at least the nodejs version it supports is 14, however more or the latest can get from there:

[Firebase Admin SDK Prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#prerequisites)

Comment: how ever still getting the issue of functions in firebase, but in google cloud it's working well